# How to use case_when based on two conditional min/max filters?

Tags: r, dplyr, switch-statement

Sample data:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   Area        Month      Measure
   <chr>       <date>       <dbl>
 1 Doncaster   2019-09-01    22.1
 2 Hull        2019-09-01    15.5
 3 Southampton 2019-09-01    28.2
 4 Doncaster   2019-10-01    19.3
 5 Hull        2019-10-01    17  
 6 Southampton 2019-10-01    26.9
 7 Doncaster   2019-11-01    19.1
 8 Hull        2019-11-01    18.2
 9 Southampton 2019-11-01    26.6
10 Doncaster   2019-12-01    19.5
11 Hull        2019-12-01    19.9
12 Southampton 2019-12-01    26.8
```

I want to mutate a new column where the minimum and maximum value in `Measure` for the latest month (2019-12-01) is given the value in `Area`, and all other rows are given the value `"Other"`. Note my real script is automated so I can't reply on manually specifying the latest month or min/max `Measure` values.

Intuitively, I thought about doing something like:

```
test %>% mutate(
  for_label = case_when(
    Month == max(Month) & Measure == min(Measure) ~ Area,
    Month == max(Month) & Measure == max(Measure) ~ Area,
    TRUE ~ "Other"
  ))
```

But this just returns a column where every value is `"Other"`. I'm assuming that matching filters are looking for a minimum and maximum global `Measure` value, and not within the selected "max" `Month`. Not sure the best solution for this.

Sample data:

```
test <- structure(list(Area = c("Doncaster", "Hull", "Southampton", "Doncaster", 
"Hull", "Southampton", "Doncaster", "Hull", "Southampton", "Doncaster", 
"Hull", "Southampton"), Month = structure(c(18140, 18140, 18140, 
18170, 18170, 18170, 18201, 18201, 18201, 18231, 18231, 18231
), class = "Date"), Measure = c(22.1, 15.5, 28.2, 19.3, 17, 26.9, 
19.1, 18.2, 26.6, 19.5, 19.9, 26.8)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to check the `min` and `max` value withing subset of data and not the entire dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  mutate(for_label = case_when(
         Month == max(Month) & Measure == min(Measure[Month == max(Month)]) ~ Area,
         Month == max(Month) & Measure == max(Measure[Month == max(Month)]) ~ Area,
         TRUE ~ "Other"))


# A tibble: 12 x 4
#   Area        Month      Measure for_label  
#   <chr>       <date>       <dbl> <chr>      
# 1 Doncaster   2019-09-01    22.1 Other      
# 2 Hull        2019-09-01    15.5 Other      
# 3 Southampton 2019-09-01    28.2 Other      
# 4 Doncaster   2019-10-01    19.3 Other      
# 5 Hull        2019-10-01    17   Other      
# 6 Southampton 2019-10-01    26.9 Other      
# 7 Doncaster   2019-11-01    19.1 Other      
# 8 Hull        2019-11-01    18.2 Other      
# 9 Southampton 2019-11-01    26.6 Other      
#10 Doncaster   2019-12-01    19.5 Doncaster  
#11 Hull        2019-12-01    19.9 Other      
#12 Southampton 2019-12-01    26.8 Southampton
```

Answer (score 1):

The `case_when` statement could also be collapsed to a single `if_else` by checking if `Measure` is an element of `range(Measure[Month == last(Month)])`:

```r
library(dplyr)

test %>%
    mutate(for_label = if_else(Month == last(Month) & Measure %in% range(Measure[Month == last(Month)]), Area, "Other"))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    Area        Month      Measure for_label  
#>    <chr>       <date>       <dbl> <chr>      
#>  1 Doncaster   2019-09-01    22.1 Other      
#>  2 Hull        2019-09-01    15.5 Other      
#>  3 Southampton 2019-09-01    28.2 Other      
#>  4 Doncaster   2019-10-01    19.3 Other      
#>  5 Hull        2019-10-01    17   Other      
#>  6 Southampton 2019-10-01    26.9 Other      
#>  7 Doncaster   2019-11-01    19.1 Other      
#>  8 Hull        2019-11-01    18.2 Other      
#>  9 Southampton 2019-11-01    26.6 Other      
#> 10 Doncaster   2019-12-01    19.5 Doncaster  
#> 11 Hull        2019-12-01    19.9 Other      
#> 12 Southampton 2019-12-01    26.8 Southampton
```